# hook_services_request_postprocess_alter() does not identify the requested resource

Tags: 7, services

According to the Services API in Drupal 7, we can use hook_services_request_postprocess_alter() to alter drupal's REST response before returning it to the user. This is useful if you want to alter the structure of an array, or strip out data we don't want returned to the API user. However, I don't see any way to identify what resource is being requested explicitly.

The Hooks passes: ($controller, $args, &$result);

The controller has semi-identifiable information, such as the callback which was fired, or the file where this resource exists. For instance, when firing a node INDEX request, we'd see:

```
[help] => List all nodes
[file] => Array
    (
        [type] => inc
        [module] => services
        [name] => resources/node_resource
    )

[callback] => _node_resource_index
[args] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => page
                [optional] => 1
                [type] => int
                [description] => The zero-based index of the page to get, defaults to 0.
                [default value] => 0
                [source] => Array
                    (
                        [param] => page
                    )

            )
```

Etc. However, there is nothing standard here across services which would tell us: "This is a node INDEX request, using the NODE endpoint."

To be clear, we're referring to node in the resource sense, such as my_host/my_endpoint/node.json. **Meaning, which of our endpoint's resources is being requested here, and what (if any) method/operation are we performing.**

I was hoping there was something standard within this hook to identify this information, as opposed to relying on more external data, such as the GET or POST variables.

Anyone have insight into this?

---

[edit]:

hook_services_request_preprocess_alter() is passed an $options array, which contains the endpoint resource and method. I need access to this information in the postprocess hook mentioned above, but don't see any clean, Drupal-way to do that. this is what I am looking for.

The array looks as follows:

```
Array(
  [version] => ,
  [resource] => node, 
  [method] => 1.json
);
```

Comment: The callback function should be plenty to identify which resource is being used - what other data were you hoping to get?

Comment: @Clive The callback could easily be altered by another hook, so I don't want to depend upon that when, say, I want to know "This was a node endpoint with a create request." There needs to be some explicit way to determine this, which cannot be altered. I'm not seeing that sort of thing in the available params of the hook.

Comment: But what's a "node endpoint" in this context? Is that a concept the services module provides that you know of? In my experience it's not - the services module defines a bunch of services on behalf of core modules, it doesn't describe a story for each or anything like that. It isn't clever enough to know that a node is one thing, and a taxonomy term is another thing, and so on, it's pretty dumb in that respect. Also an 'endpoint' refers to where you're getting the data from (i.e. site.com/my_endpoint), so you already _have_ that information when you make the API call...

Comment: ...services are supposed to be (and are) generic enough that they don't depend on any particular endpoint being used, which is likely why it's not available. I think you're looking for the Services module to define a Grammar for you, which you can parse to get contextual, human-readable information about the resources its using. To the best of my knowledge no such thing exists

Comment: @Clive The person making the API call has the information that they are hitting endpoint/node.json, but Drupal should provide a way to get that as well. That is something it knows, and not something that can be changed by hooks. That information is not compromising the generic nature of services, and is very important in context of some of the callbacks being exposed in services, particularly as defined in services.alter.api.php. There must be some way to determine that information within the callbacks, without relying on the $_SERVER globals.

Comment: @Clive Clearly, Drupal already has the information about the resource being requested, as it provides a subset of the resource array definitions (where the callback, args, etc are defined.) So, there must be a way to do this request, and it is clearly not overreaching the scope of services, since Drupal has made part of this context available within the $controller parameter in the hook.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for me to say exactly? The Services module, to the best of my knowledge, having used it for a few years, doesn't have the functionality you require (and I can see a strong argument for _why_ it doesn't give you that context; you disagree, that's fine, all good). But whether it _should_ have it or _should be able_ to have it is kind of incidental if it **doesn't** have it, no? If the functionality isn't there, the only way to get it is to patch the Services module and open a feature request on its issue queue to share the progress

Comment: I should say that I haven't read every single line of the Services module, so maybe what you're after _is_ buried in there somewhere after all. If you want to go hunting, look for calls to `module_implements()`, and see where it gets the parameter data from that it passes through to the hook invocations. That should make it reasonably clear whether the data you want is available in the context you find yourself in

Comment: @Clive Looking at hook_services_requests_preprocess_alter(), the options array passed in there does provide the resource and method. I simply need that information in the POSTprocess hook. I was thinking of grabbing that in preprocess, and propogating it somehow, but only the options param is alterable in proprocess. EX: Options contains: Array(    [version] =>  ,   [resource] => node,   [method] => 1.json). Any thoughts as to how to get this info into the post, as cleanly as possible, and without using globals or session variables?

Comment: @Clive Apologies if I was being unclear here. I've updated my question to help clarify exactly what I'm looking for, and the precedent set in a previous hook within the API, showing that this information is not out of scope to the service. I think there is some confusion here as to the boundaries between RESTFUL web services and Drupal's internal hook structure / internal web services calls.

Comment: I stand corrected :) I haven't got a copy of Services in front of me (not actually working on Drupal today, probably shouldn't be here!). Once I get home I'll see if I can find anything, but the way you've described it sounds like it might need a bit of patching...

Comment: @Clive Thanks for participating, and giving some of your insight, all the same. Even if we had a disagreement for a minute, the challenging point of view gets the braining moving. Thanks for taking a look! If I find anything myself, I'll be sure to pass along my findings.

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look to $args array, you can find your node type, for example I have a content type "video", my $args are like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => *
    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => video
            [uid] => 92
        )

    [3] => 2
)
```

Then $args[2] has the content type (because I set it like a parameter in my resource:
http://site.local/api/v1/node?parameters[type]=video&parameters[uid]=92&pagesize=2&page=2

Comment: You're not wrong, but I really try not to depend upon the args array in this case. Drupal should offer context within the function variables to determine this, not some external source. That is what I was hoping to find.